# GGPlot multiple lines ending at the same point

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have been trying to plot the data from my dataset with ggplot2. Below, you can see the graph. The number of the observations are placed on the x-axis, whereas the scores obtained on a behavior rating scale are plotted on the y-axis. These scores are collected in two consecutive conditions (A = baseline, B = intervention) whose length is different for each subject.

```
df <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "
    case measure session phase_id outcome condition
1      1       3       1        A       4         A
2      1       3       2        A      10         A
3      1       3       3        A      10         A
4      1       3       4        B      10         B
5      1       3       5        B      10         B
6      1       3       6        B      10         B
7      1       3       7        B      12         B
8      1       3       8        B      10         B
9      1       3       9        B      20         B
10     3       3       1        A      13         A
11     3       3       2        A      12         A
12     3       3       3        A       5         A
13     3       3       4        A       0         A
14     3       3       5        A      10         A
15     3       3       6        A       4         A
16     3       3       7        A       3         A
17     3       3       8        B       4         B
18     3       3       9        B      14         B
19     3       3      10        B      25         B
20     3       3      11        B      25         B
21     3       3      12        B      20         B
22     3       3      13        B      25         B
23     3       3      14        B      24         B
24     3       3      15        B      13         B
25     6       3       1        A       7         A
26     6       3       2        A       6         A
27     6       3       3        A       9         A
28     6       3       4        A       0         A
29     6       3       5        A       9         A
30     6       3       6        B       6         B
31     6       3       7        B      14         B
32     6       3       8        B       6         B
33     6       3       9        B       7         B
")
```

What I would like to do is to establish a point in the middle of the graph where all the data associated with the phase A end so that the Phase A will end at the same point and the phase B will start at the same point for every participant.

```
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(session, outcome, color)) +
  geom_line(aes(group = case, color = condition), size = 0.1, alpha = 0.4) +
  geom_smooth(aes(color = condition), size = 2, method = "lm") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

**UPDATE**

This would be the solution that I would like to have (maybe without continous lines between the two phase).

[image]

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I don't understand the shifting of Sessions well, I guess you want something like this:

```
endVal <- max( df[df$phase_id=="A","session"] )
```

endVal computes the last value in the phase A. Variable session2 is shifted according to this value.

```
addToCase <- df %>%
 filter(phase_id=="A") %>%
 group_by(case) %>% 
 summarise(addValue =  endVal - max(session) )

dataPhases <- merge(df, addToCase, by="case") %>%
 mutate(session2 = session + addValue)

dataPhaseA <- dataPhases %>%
 filter(phase_id == "A")  

dataPhaseB <- dataPhases %>%
 filter(phase_id == "B")
```

And ggplot:

```
ggplot(dataPhaseA,
  aes(x=session2, y=outcome, colour=phase_id, group=case) ) + 
 geom_line() + 
 geom_smooth(aes(group=phase_id), size = 2, method = "lm") +
 geom_line(data=dataPhaseB,
  aes(x=session2, y=outcome, colour=phase_id, group=case) ) + 
 geom_smooth(data=dataPhaseB, aes(group=phase_id), size = 2, method = "lm") + 
 theme_minimal() +
 theme(legend.position = "none")
```

Plot looks like:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @Lstat! I provided a new graph (I changed the data in my dataset manually). Hopefully, what I would like to do will be clearer.

Comment: Just to clarify: 1/ you don't want a goem_point ("is to establish a point in the middle of the graph") 2/ geom_smooth is not based on condition (conditions are overlapping)

Comment: Thanks! Exactly, my point was to find a way to give new numbers to sessions of all cases based on the case who had the longest phase A so that cases could end at the same point and the two lines in the graph didn't overlap.

Comment: I think that shifting the sessions will help the readers to see the difference between the two phases. I might end up using your previous solution but I think two separate lines are less confusing because there is no overlap.

Comment: I'm glad it helped. If it improves interpretability then go with it! I called this new variable session2 as it's not an original scale anymore. That might confuse readers if it's not described properly in the text... Good luck with your future endeavouRs!